# How to fire a jquery function onchange from an html element in highchart event on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Highchart container

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
              /// code goes here

              plotOptions:{
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                 //
                                 if(this.series.name=="Positive") {
                                    <%if(posTitle.get(0).equals("NoValue")){
                                        //do nothing
                                    }else{
                                    %>
                                    $report.html(
                                            '<table>'+
                                            '<tr><td><b>Sentiment</b></td><td><b>News</b></td><td><b>Date</b></td><td><b>News Courtesy</b></td><td><b>User Opinion</b></td></tr>' +
                                            <%   for(int tempTitle=0;tempTitle<1;tempTitle++){%>
                                            '<tr><td>'+this.series.name+'</td><td><a href='+"<%=posTitle.get(tempTitle)%>"+' target = "_blank">'+"<%=posNews.get(tempTitle)%>"+'</a></td><td>'+"<%=posDate.get(tempTitle)%>"+'</td><td>iproperty.com.sg</td><td>***<select class="check" id="op1" >***<option value="0.5" selected="selected">Positive</option><option value="1">Very Positive</option><option value="0">Neutral</option><option value="-0.5">Negative</option><option value="-1">Very Negative</option></select></td></tr>'+
                                            <%}%>
                                            '</table>');
                                    <%}%>
                                }
```

So when I try to fire the above onchange select within $report.html() . It is not calling the below function.
so the function is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.check').on('change',function ()
        {   alert(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "mainPageForOpinion.jsp", //this is my servlet
                data: {
                    output: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function(){
                    $('#output').html("Updated");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Can someone help me! 
Thanks

Comment: add `error` property to your ajax to help yourself debug, and you need to point to a `WebMethod` in your servlet, not the servlet itself

Comment: @david: accepted but the primary concern is not with ajax but it is the onchange event which doesnt even fire the function though I bind the class.

Comment: Solved. Problem was the script should be inside the $report.html() to fire the event as the $report.html() is loaded over onclick event.

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: Hi all here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H32qN/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `$(".check").change()` after `$report.html(...)` - to make sure, that change is called after you created new element in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating `select` tag with `class=check` dynamically, you need to bind change event using document object. See below jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change','.check',function ()// bind change event using document object
        {   alert(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "mainPageForOpinion.jsp", //this is my servlet
                data: {
                    output: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function(){
                    $('#output').html("Updated");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: It doesnt work.. I personally feel the onchange firing is from the $report.html(..) which doesn't recognize there is a function in the document as it itself is in the function onclick of the data points in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the script should be inside the $report.html() to fire the event as the $report.html() is loaded over onclick event.

fiddle: jsfiddle.net/H32qN/4